# Getting Javascript error: "Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null"

Tags: javascript, html

I've been scratching my head for a while now, I'm a novice with Javascript, but this is a first for me. Here is some very simple html and javascript code that's causing the error in the title:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script>
        document.getElementById("game-column").innerHTML = "test";
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="game-container">
        <div id="card-column" name="card-column"></div>
        <div id="game-column" name="game-column"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm mainly using firefox for testing.

For some reason it's complaining in the console when I refresh the webpage, however when I run the JS command in the console it seems to work fine. See image below.

Thanks for any responses.

[image]

Comment: Move the script to the bottom of the body.

Comment: your script is triggered before the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the script to the bottom instead:

like this:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="game-container">
      <div id="card-column" name="card-column"></div>
      <div id="game-column" name="game-column"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("game-column").innerHTML = "test";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I like having blond moments late at night. xP

Comment: Marking the answer accepted for help me :)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening because your DOM isn't loaded before your JavaScript is executed. See here for an explanation and solution: https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded. Alternatively, you could move your javascript to below your HTML!